# "Inception" situation with wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

The title is amusing , I know. Its like movie "Inception" situation .Dream in a dream in a dream .
Hi everyone ,I am using wxpython to make an app.
I want to achieve something like this .(This is just idea of the problem)

```
func1(self,event):
      some widgets added
      func2
func2(self,event):
      remove previous widgets (by using event.GetEventObject().GetParent().Hide())
      add new ones
      func3
func3(self,event):
      remove widgets added in func2
      recall widgets added in func1 (event.GetEventObject().GetParent().Show())
```

I have traversed too much inside , like 3 times jumping from functions to other nested
functions that i have no track of event .

If i store the ids of events (in a list) with

```
   event.GetId()
```

while traversing in every function , is there a way if i can use those ids to 
replace

```
event.GetEventObject().GetParent().Show()
event.GetEventObject().GetParent().Hide()
```

with

```
id1.GetEventObject().GetParent().Hide()
id2.GetEventObject().GetParent().Show()
```

I just want to know this kind of thing is possible ?
Or theres a better simpler way ?

Answer (score 0):

If any still is in such trouble , I found some ways...
First of all , you don't need to use IDs for this.....Much simpler way is 
create different panels........
When you want to hide one , you can simply do

```
panelname.Hide()
```

When you want to show another ,

```
panelname.Show() # Or this also works (event.GetEventObject().GetParent().Show()\Hide())
```

Note : 1) Remember to give all widgets (buttons etc) individual IDs (or -1 will do).
2) You can also create your overlapping panels with a function call too.(example - After a button is clicked).
3) Also you can create a common panel ( a parent panel ) and then create child panels and in the **init** body . And then you can simply hide and show these panels in a function binded (may be with a button etc) .

I solved my problem like this . Did'nt need to use GetId() . But there might be others ways. So do share if you have some other idea.I hope this helps someone someday...Thank you all.